# Trying to get property of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\tables\index.php

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

I am using the following codes but I am getting the some errors saying -

> Trying to get property of non-object in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\tables\index.php.

I have following codes-

```
<?php
require 'simple_html_dom.php';

$html = file_get_html('http://mkp.gem.gov.in/oem-cartridge/samsung-111s-toner-rst/p-5116877-68482402616-cat.html');

foreach($html->find('div#sellers-table-wrap table tbody tr') as $article) {
    $item['name']   = $article->find('td.seller-name div.seller-info span.seller-info-caption', 0)->plaintext;
    $item['price']  = $article->find('td.offer-price span.variant-final-price span.m-w', 0)->plaintext;
    $articles[] = $item;
}
echo "<pre>";
print_r($articles);

?>
```

update: I also tried this, but not working:

```
    foreach($html->find('div#sellers-table-wrap table tbody tr') as $article) {
  if (count($article->find('td.seller-name div.seller-info span.seller-info-caption')) > 0) {
    $item['name']   = $article->find('td.seller-name div.seller-info span.seller-info-caption', 0)->plaintext;
    $item['price']   = $article->find('td.offer-price span.variant-final-price span.m-w', 0)->plaintext;
  }
    $articles[] = $item;
}
echo "<pre>";
print_r($articles);
```

Comment: Which line is the error on?

Comment: $item['name']   = $article->find('td.seller-name div.seller-info span.seller-info-caption', 0)->plaintext;
    $item['price']  = $article->find('td.offer-price span.variant-final-price span.m-w', 0)->plaintext

Comment: A - on php.net, there is no `file_get_html` function, what is this? B - `file_get_html` is a function, not a class, therefore you can't use it as a class

Comment: @SamSwift웃 It's from of [Simple HTML DOM](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16165320/notice-trying-to-get-property-of-non-object-in-c-xampp-htdocs

Comment: Please go through this- http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

Comment: @Barmar, Please help me why I am getting such errors.

Comment: I would guess that it couldn't find that part of the html, so there was no object that would contain `plaintext`. Try first breaking it up as `$test = $article->find('td.seller-name div.seller-info span.seller-info-caption', 0);` then verify what `$next` is by `var_dump($next);`. If it breaks on `$article->find`, then `var_dump($article);`

Comment: In the edit, the `$articles[] = $item;` should be inside the `if`.

Comment: but elements are repeating in array?

Comment: Thank you @Barmar, It worked. Please update your answer as I want to upvote your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the selector in your loop to:

```
foreach($html->find('div#sellers-table-wrap > table > tbody > tr') as $article) {
```

There are other tables nested inside this table, so you're looping over their rows as well. But they don't have elements that match the selectors you're using to assign to `$item['name']` and `$item['price']`, so those `find()` calls are returning `null`, which causes the errors. This selector just matches the rows in the top-level table.

You can also add a check:

```
foreach($html->find('div#sellers-table-wrap > table > tbody > tr') as $article) {
    $item = array();
    $caption = $article->find('td.seller-name div.seller-info span.seller-info-caption', 0);
    $mw = $article->find('td.offer-price span.variant-final-price span.m-w', 0);
    if ($caption && $mw) {
        $item['name'] = $caption->plaintext;
        $item['price'] = $mw->plaintext;
        $articles[] = $item;
    }
}
```

Comment: No effect, returning same result.

Comment: What does `var_dump($article->find('td.seller-name div.seller-info span.seller-info-caption', 0))` show?

Comment: NULL is the result.

Comment: I'm not sure why that's happening, all the rows seem to have those elements. But you could add a check that it's not null before trying to access the property.